# Getting "" in the file instead of " which is not expected

Tags: excel, vbscript, excel-2007, vba

There is a code in button click where the workbooks are saved into a local text files.

workbook contains the below info:

> CRITICAL; insert into ifparam
>   values(3498,'TAT_UNALLOCTRADESREC','STRING','IF(STRING(C5)=STRING("TCE
>   - External Hedge"),STRING("E"),IF(STRING(C5)=STRING("TCE - Internal Hedge"),STRING("I"),STRING(C5)))');

But output comes as CRITICAL;

```
insert into ifparam values(3498,'TAT_UNALLOCTRADESREC','STRING','IF(STRING(C5)=STRING(""TCE - External Hedge""),STRING(""E""),IF(STRING(C5)=STRING(""TCE - Internal Hedge""),STRING(""I""),STRING(C5)))');
```

Issue is where ever there is " we are getting "" in the output.
Can anyone help me in getting this as it is in the workbook i.e; single double quote " instead of ""

Please suggest if any code change needed.
Code used :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim xlBook As Workbook, xlSheet As Worksheet
    Dim strOutputFileName As String
    Dim n As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim MyData As String, strData() As String, MyArray() As String
    Dim strPath As String

    strPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path '<~~ \\plyalnppd3sm\d$\Temp\Arun\TAT\

    ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs strPath & "\Temp.xls"

    Set xlBook = Workbooks.Open(strPath & "\Temp.xls")

    For Each xlSheet In xlBook.Worksheets
        If xlSheet.Name <> "User_provided_data" Then
            strOutputFileName = strPath & "\" & xlSheet.Name & ".zup"
            xlSheet.SaveAs Filename:=strOutputFileName, FileFormat:=xlTextMSDOS



    n = n + 1

            ReDim Preserve MyArray(n)
            MyArray(n) = strOutputFileName
            Debug.Print strOutputFileName
        End If
    Next

    xlBook.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Kill strPath & "\Temp.xls"

    For i = 1 To UBound(MyArray)
        '~~> open the files in One go and store them in an array
        Open MyArray(i) For Binary As #1
        MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
        Get #1, , MyData
        Close #1
        strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)

        '~~> Write to the text file
        Open MyArray(i) For Output As #1

        '~~> Loop through the array and check if the start and end has "
        '~~> And if it does then ignore those and write to the text file
        For j = LBound(strData) To UBound(strData)
            If Left(strData(j), 1) = """" And Right(strData(j), 1) = """" Then
                strData(j) = Mid(strData(j), 2, Len(strData(j)) - 2)
            End If
            Print #1, strData(j)
        Next j
        Close #1
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: @kelly what are the changes you made..please let me know so that i can gain knowledege

Comment: you forget to quote first and last line of code

Comment: @kelly ok..Can you suggest how i can get rid of the error i am getting please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest solution without looking at your code too much - Add in this line before outputting `strData(j)` to the text file:

```
strData(j) = Replace(strData(j), """""", """")
```

I'm sure there are nicer ways, but this is a very simple, quick and dirty fix!